# Change negative number format in Bi-Publisher RTF

Tags: java, oracle, report, rtf, bi-publisher

I am doing an RTF I hope you can help me, how could I change the negative number format?

Change "-" for "()"

For example I have:
821,292.87
-146,983.06
-671.64
503,927.51

And I would like to see them in the following way:
821,292.87
(146,983.06)
(671.64)
503,927.51

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PR` format model to get negative numbers in angle brackets:

```sql
SQL> select to_char(-146983.06,'999g999g999d99PR','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''') l 
       from dual;

L
----------------
    <146,983.06>
```

Or I would do this with `regexp_replace` and `to_char`:

```sql
regexp_replace( to_char(-146983.06,'tm9','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,'''), 
                     '-(.*)','(\1)' )
```

Example:

```sql
SQL> select regexp_replace( to_char(-146983.06,'tm9','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,'''), 
                        '-(.*)','(\1)' ) l 
       from dual;

L
------------------------------
(146983.06)
```

Comment: https://imdjkoch.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-format-numbers-in-bi-publisher-template/

Comment: You can also use Microsoft number format mask, just use  Pattern separator. The first pattern will be used for
positive numbers and the second for negative numbers